# how to count data occurrence between certain DateTime range in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am sorry for this kind of newbie question, but it is quite hard for me. My `MySQL` table holds high-frequency stock prices. On each trading date, data starts from day 1 `18:00` to day 2 `17:00`. I want to count the data occurrence for each trading day between the above trading hour. I know how to count for a single day just as following code

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-08-25 18:00:00' AND '2021-08-26 17:00:00'
```

But how to count all the days in the table?

**My table looks like this:**
[image]

**What I want to looks like this:**
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appreciate that your "day" starts at 6pm.  So, we can normalize each datetime by subtracting 18 hours, and then aggregate:

```sql
SELECT DATE(date - INTERVAL 18 HOUR), COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY 1;
```